# How can I install a folder/files to the images directory for a Joomla component?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7, joomla1.6, joomla2.5

I know how to add system images to the /media folder, but is there a way to have a folder and files added into the /images folder (i.e. the place where Media Manager expects to find files?

Comment: At what point? Ie. during the install of a component or ...

Comment: you can of course add another folder inside the images folder. Some components allow you to type in the image location manually and some automatically look in the default images folder in which case you will have to edit the component code manually.

Comment: I mean during installation. Is there a part of the manifest that can do this?  
I guess my other option is to do it in the install script - creating the folder is easy, but I'm not sure how I would then move the images from the install package to the main images folder.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Joomla Component Creator. http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/

You can add a field of the type "media" that will show the whole media manager and allow you to upload to it and insert it into the item you are editing.

Alternatively you can add it manually. Here is the documentation:

http://docs.joomla.org/Media_form_field_type